# ocaml memoization failed when applied to Fibonacci series

Tags: ocaml

I tried to use memoization technique to optimize the caculation of Fibonacci. My code is:

```
let memo f = 
  let vtable = ref [] in
  let rec match_function x vt=
    match vt with
      |(x',y)::_ when x=x' -> y
      |_::l ->
        match_function x l
      |[] ->
        let y = (f x) in
        vtable :=  (x,y):: !vtable;
        y 
  in
  (fun x -> (match_function x !vtable));;

let rec ggfib = function
  0|1 as i -> i
  |x -> ggfib(x-1) + ggfib(x-2);;

let memoggfib = memo ggfib;;

let running_time f x =
  let start_time = Sys.time () in
  let y = f x in
  let finish_time = Sys.time() in
  Printf.printf "Time lapse:%f\n"  (finish_time -. start_time);
  y;;


running_time ggfib 30;;
running_time memoggfib 30;;
```

The output is:

```
Time lapse:0.357187
Time lapse:0.353663
```

The difference is not that much.. Why?? And even worse, when I tried to calculate Fibonacci at 40 using

```
running_time ggfib 40;;
running_time memoggfib 40;;
```

The program appears to run into a infinite loop and stop outputting.

What is wrong here? What problem I did not take care of?

I changed the code above, to introduce a 'static' vtable for memoization.

```
let rec ggfib = function
  0|1 as i -> i
  |x -> ggfib(x-1) + ggfib(x-2);;

let running_time x0 =
  let vtable = ref [] in
  let start_time = Sys.time () in
  let x = ref 1 in
  let rec match_function ff x vt=
    match vt with
      |(x',y)::_ when x=x' -> y
      |_::l ->
        match_function ff x l
      |[] ->
        let y = (ff x) in
        vtable :=  (x,y):: !vtable;
        y 
  in
  let y=ref 1 in
  while !x<x0 do
    y:= match_function ggfib !x !vtable;
    x:=!x+1;
  done;
  let finish_time = Sys.time() in
  Printf.printf "Time lapse:%f\n"  (finish_time -. start_time);
  y;;


let running_time2 x0=
  let start_time = Sys.time () in
  let x = ref 1 in
  while !x<x0 do
  ggfib !x;
  x:=!x+1;
  done;
  let finish_time = Sys.time() in
  Printf.printf "Time lapse:%f\n"  (finish_time -. start_time);;

running_time 40;;
running_time2 30;;
```

It still acts as the basically same. I didn't see a significant improvement....

```
Time lapse:0.581918
Time lapse:0.577813
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(* a "derecursified" version of fibonacci: recursive calls are
  replaced by calls to a function passed as parameter *)
let rec fib_derec f = function
| 0|1 as i -> i
| n -> f (n - 1) + f (n - 2)

(* to get the fibonacci back we need to compute a fixpoint:
   fib_derec should get passed 'fib' as parameter,
   which we will define in term of fib_derec
*)
let rec fib n = fib_derec fib n

let test = Array.init 10 fib
(* [|0; 1; 1; 2; 3; 5; 8; 13; 21; 34|] *)

(* we can make this construction generic *)
let rec fix derec input = derec (fix derec) input

let fib = fix fib_derec

let test = Array.init 10 fib
(* [|0; 1; 1; 2; 3; 5; 8; 13; 21; 34|] *)


(* Trick: we can use this tying-the-knot operator to insert
   memoization "between the recursive calls" of the recursive function *)

let rec memo_fix table derec =
  fun input ->
    try Hashtbl.find table input with Not_found ->
      let result = derec (memo_fix table derec) input in
      Hashtbl.add table input result;
      result

let fib_table = Hashtbl.create 100 
let fib = memo_fix fib_table fib_derec

let test = Array.init 10 fib
(* [|0; 1; 1; 2; 3; 5; 8; 13; 21; 34|] *)

let test2 = fib 1000
(* -591372213: overflow, but quick result *)
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! Please allow me sometime to think over your posting. A lot to chew for a new learner.

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like you're just memoizing the outermost calls.  The inner calls are to ggfib, not to (memo ggfib).

When you call memoggfib, the memo function will remember the value of the outermost call.  However, the inner calls are handled by ggfib (the function that you passed to memo).  If you look at the definition of ggfib, you see that it calls itself.  It doesn't call (memo ggfib).

I don't see a way to turn an ordinary (recursive) function into a memoized one.  It won't automatically call the memoized version of itself internally.

If you start with a function that's intended to be memoized, I still see problems "tying the knot".

Comment: sorry, i don't get it. could you expand it a little bit?

Comment: @lkahtz: the issue is that `ggfib` calls `ggfib`, and not `memo ggfib`. That means your call to `memoggfib` will do one check to see if it's been called with that parameter before, then it calls `ggfib`; which calls `ggfib` many times.